# What is the difference between ものですから and just ですから?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I am currently studying this grammar point ~ものですから, and I understand that the meaning is "because; the reason is"

However it seems to me that there is no difference if we omit the もの. So can someone enlightening me, what is the difference between:

eg.

私は忙しいものですから.
and
私は忙しいですから.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q14134469774
>
> 「…ですから」と「…ものですから」の区別があるでしょうか
>
> 事故で電車が遅れたものですから、遅くなってすみません。

Esp. when making / stating excuses, this form  [ . . . ものですから、]  is often used.

It's hard to explain, but it has this < je ne sais quoi >  droll quality.

---

> 私は忙しいですから.

One problem is that  [ 忙しいです ] is not considered grammatical by purists.

According to the purists, the correct form is 忙しゅうございます

〈 形容詞+「です」 〉    . . . -- I probably say this in speech, but i try to avoid it in writing.

> http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1256554757
>
> 形容詞+「です」の形は、厳密に言えば誤用です。ただ、一般的には許容されています。 ........
>
> 「強いです」の類いは、厳密に言えば誤用です。「強かったです」なども同様で、厳密に言えば誤用です。

---

I had much more trouble finding pages on it than i thought -- one indication that  〈 形容詞+「です」 〉  is more accepted / acceptable today than 20 years ago.

> http://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/7428403.html
>
> ただ、〈形容詞+「です」〉は昭和27年の段階で文化庁が許容しています。そのせいか、現代では辞書や文法書も許容しているようです。
>
> 外国人向けの日本語教育の教科書も 〈形容詞+「です」〉 を採用しています。
>
> しかし、その一方で年配者などのなかには 〈形容詞+「です」〉 に抵抗を感じる人が多いようです。

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I think the first link you provided is exactly what I'm looking for. I think my understanding of the difference is a lot clearer now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ものですから/もんだから is a construction that explains the reason for an unfortunate situation.

So for your example, it would be more fitting to use it in (as an example) the following sentence:

A:昨日のパーティーに来れなくて残念でしたね。Too bad you couldn't come to yesterday's party。

B:私は忙しいものですから。I'm a busy person. (so I couldn't go)

NOTE: This does sound kind of cold for this particular example. :P.

http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=monodakara

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I understand that ものですから/もんだから is a construction that explains the reason for an unfortunate situation. But what I failed to understand is the difference between ものですから and just ですから. Both have the same meaning to me.